# JQuery transition only works twice

Tags: jquery, loops, rotation, transition, repeat

I am currently learning how to use JQuery and Web Design.

This simple starts with ".back" pre rotated to 180deg.
Every 3 seconds it rotates the ".flipper" by 180deg, swapping the ".back" and ".front".

For some reason, only flips to the ".back" and back to the ".front" once. 
Does anyone know why?

I first found this setup from a tutorial displaying how to flip these on hover event.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    var deg = '180deg';

    function RotateFlipper()
    {
        $(".flipper").transition({rotateY: degree});
        deg = deg = '180deg' ? '0' : '180deg'
    }

    window.setInterval(RotateFlipper, 3000);

</script>
```

Comment: Is deg = deg = '180deg' a typo? It seems like it should be deg = deg == '180deg'

Comment: deg = deg = '180deg' ? '0' : '180deg' is short for if(deg == '180deg') deg = '0' else deg = '180'

Comment: Yes, but when you say (deg = '180deg' ? '0' : '180deg'), the ternary operator evaluates (deg = '180deg'), which sets deg to '180deg' and returns '180deg', which is interpreted as True (since it is a non-empty string). This will always result in '0' returning. I believe you meant to say (deg == '180deg') as a comparison instead of an assignment.

Comment: Omg hahahahaha I never noticed I did that!

        deg = (deg == '180deg') ? '0' : '180deg'